# second level cache with formula property

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Using nHib 3.2, I'm interested in caching all my entity's properties, except for a formula property which I would like to be calculated with each `Get`.
Is this possible?

here's my mapping:

```
    public TransactionNHibernateMapping()
            {
                Table("TransactionInfo");
                Id(transaction => transaction.TransactionId, m => m.Generator(Generators.GuidComb));
                Cache(c =>
            {
                c.Include(CacheInclude.All);
                c.Usage(CacheUsage.ReadWrite);
            });

                Property(transaction => transaction.HighestSeverity, m => m.Formula("(Select max(LogEntryInfo.Severity) from LogEntryInfo where LogEntryInfo.TransactionId = TransactionId)"));
            }
```

now, although 2nd level cache is enabled, this entity is always re-loaded from the database.
If I remove the `HighestSeverity` property mapping, caching works as expected.

I've tried playing with the `Generated` option of the formula field, but that didn't seem to help.
any other ideas?